# Get most recent post using WP-API JS

Tags: javascript, wordpress, api, wp-api

I'd like to be able to return the most recent Wordpress post from my blog using the WP-API (Version 2).

I can't work out what to put after:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/
```

Any help is much appreciated. - Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this - `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=1`

Comment: It answer is deprecated.

Comment: Rather than using filter on URL params you need to use it like this  ?per_page=1

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/#pagination-parameters) you specify the number of records to return in one request with the parameter `per_page` so `/wp/v2/posts?per_page=1` will return only the first post.

Comment: It is a valid answer that works.

Answer (score 1):

public Page: string = "**posts?per_page=num&offset=num&_embed&category_id=num**';";

'***categories***=num'be used alternatively.

Answer (score 0):

### Latest Posts with Restful API

---

[This very simple but useful plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/latest-posts-with-restful-api/) can help with rewrite ajax with **cache** ability:

**Installation** (step by step):

In your WordPress website admin panel

1. Go to *Plugins*.
2. Click on *Add new*.
3. Search for "restful api".
4. install "Latest Posts with Restful API" and Activate it.
5. At the Settings -> Permalink JUST CLICK SAVE to update site permalink address.

**You can** :

1. Show latest posts + **category name** and **post featured Image**

> ```
> (site_URL)/api/latestposts/(Number of POSTs - like 30)
> ```

2. Get one post data + category name and post featured Image

> ```
>  (site_URL)/api/getpost/(post ID)
> ```

3. Get one VIP category post called "mobile_app_more"

> ```
>  (site_URL)/api/moretab/1
> ```

[Download Latest Posts with Restful API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/latest-posts-with-restful-api/)

[Plugin GitHub Page](https://github.com/akbarijedi/wp_restAPI_news_feed/releases)

Hope this help : ) especially when "wp-json" is **disable by firewall** plugin!

---